# Unity crashes when opening a project

Tags: unity

Why does this happen?

I'm new to Unity development. I have installed Unity yesterday (2015-09-06). This is the error that I get:

[image]

Comment: How much RAM does your machine have?

Comment: Another question is _when_ does this happen?

Comment: whe try to import all Assets to project this happens. without inport assets I could create the project

Answer (score 5):

Read the error:

> System out of memory!

Maybe there is a lack of RAM on your system. Try closing some (if any) background applications to free up some RAM.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely your system is out of RAM to be able to make the required memory allocations for opening the project. Have you tried a reboot?

If a reboot doesn't help, have a look to see what image file you have in your Unity assets folder that is around 128mb. I would guess as the crash is within Unity's **Image.cpp** source code, and the allocation is for 134217744 bytes or 128mb, that it is unable to find memory to create that large image file.